# SharePoint 2013 - How to add an action to a Callout

Tags: 2013, javascript, client-object-model

I want to add a custom action on the default Callout for Document Libraries.

The only instructions I could find on this subject show how to override the entire FooterTemplate on an existing Callout panel. See here: http://www.estruyf.be/blog/hiding-the-social-actions-follow-share-from-the-document-libraries-in-sharepoint-2013/

The problem with this approach is that other custom actions added by other pieces of code are lost. So it is necessary to account for them. For example, the "Follow" action gets lost (I believe it is added by some SharePoint feature).

Is there a way of simply getting the current Callout from the context and invoke addAction on it? On what event should I do that?

Comment: I know it's been almost three years, but do you have another link that displays something else than 404? ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

jhrecife,

I wrote a blog post about this topic. You can read it over here: [Adding a custom action to a callout in SharePoint 2013](https://www.eliostruyf.com/adding-a-custom-action-to-a-callout-in-sharepoint-2013/)

The thing is to override the current footer template and do a call to the default action populator.

Regards,
EStruyf